# Cargo - Page Stack Hover Grid Overflowing To Next Page

Tags: html, css

Working on cargo and looking for a little help - pieced together a grid hover function, when moving over an image to reveal the background - preview here: https://projectnativeinformant.online/mkh-stack

I'm just trying to stack pages before and after this section - but the grid spills over onto the following page. Any advice on how to fix this?

All help much appreciated, very much a novice!
Thanks

```
#bg {
width: 110vw;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
}

#bg .grid {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
background: url('https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/9d531cf366a9bb455a685225b3206ba6c93a709af380cf4f41c94abac0a03170/Screenshot-2021-04-13-at-20.06.31.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This is then followed by a bunch of

```
<div id="bg">
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. I needed to add `overflow: hidden;` to the styles.